# How to partition a div into 3 parts separated by borders in html

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar on the top of a page.In the next div below navigation bar,I'm trying to partition a div into 3 columns which are separated by their borders but not separated by background color.

I want the background color to be unique for all the 3 partitions.I tried using frameset and frame tags.But it is partitioning the entire page.I don't want an entire page to be partitioned into 3 columns.

Firstly,at the top of the page,I want the navigation bar to be placed and later I want one particular div of that page to be partitioned into 3 columns.How can I achieve this?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

```
My html code:

     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="Admin">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Scripts/Home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://caitp.github.io/ng-media/ng-media.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body class="home">
        <div ng-controller="Home" class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <img src="images/logo.jpg" style="width: 100px;">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="home1.html">HOME</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">EXPLORE OCR <span
                                    class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
                                </ul></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+FEATURES <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
                                </ul></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">HELP <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
                                </ul></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="signIn.html" style="padding-left: 332px;">SignIn</a></li>
                            <li><a href="logOut.html">LogOut</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    <div>
// I'm trying to partition this div into 3 columns(left,center,right).
   </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't know how to keep the code in the fiddle

Comment: I had edited my code in parixit.I have used these external resources:<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>

</head>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods. I usually like to use `display: table-cell`. Something like:

```
<div class="three-columns">
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Content Here -->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Content Here -->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Content Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And

```
div.three-columns {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Prevent spaces between cells */
}
div.three-columns > .column {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.33%;
    border-left: <BORDER DEFINITION HERE>
}
div.three-columns > .column:first-child {
    /* Since we only want borders between the elements, remove the leftmost border */
    border-left: none; 
}
```

The table layout engine requires every cell in a row be the same height. Simply add borders.

Comment: I'm unable to see the div at all by using the above code.Do I need to change the code over here.

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya its working for me. You did put content in the three columns and substitute something where I wrote <BORDER DEFINITION HERE> right?? Here's a fiddle showing it in action. https://jsfiddle.net/xd6o0nw5/

Comment: Ya,it's working fine for me.Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: can we increase the border height over here

Comment: If you want the columns to be a certain fixed height add `height: <SOME NUMBER HERE>` to the div.three-columns rule. If you want to just add some whitespace around the column contents add `padding: <SOME NUMBER HERE>` to the div.three-columns > .column rule.

Comment: Those are just two options. It doesn't really matter how you resize or reposition the content. The borders will always stretch from the top to the bottom of the div.

Comment: ok den.I'm able to increase the border height, if I'm trying to increase the content.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear with your question. But is the below code suiting your requirement. I have added the css inline.

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;width: calc(100%/3);background:red">left</div>
    <div style="float: left;width: calc(100%/3);background:pink">center</div>
    <div style="float: left;width: calc(100%/3);background: blue">right</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I don't want the div to be partitioned by its background-color.I want the div to be partitioned into 3 columns which is separated by their borders

Comment: then you can add a border instead of the background color. And add the background color to the container div

Answer (score 0):

you'd rather need HTML Table here. if you still insist on using divs then use it as a CSS Table

Comment: HTML tables have unnecessary implications. CSS tables use the same layout but take less code and don't cause the same 'issues' as HTML tables. Also your example seems to be rows, not columns.

Comment: the pen wasn't saved properly due to internet delay. updated it. should be fine now

Comment: It is indeed fixed now. P.S. you can safely leave out the table-row if you're not planning to have more than one row. The browser will fill in for it.

Comment: yes you can remove it, but as for the code i provided, the table had a predefined height

Comment: @TheQuestioner unable to redirect to the CodePen link you have provided

Answer (score 0):

**this is the solution**

This is the html code, inside your html

```
<div class="maindiv">
 <div id="divone" class="subdiv"></div>
 <div id="divtwo" class="subdiv"></div>
 <div id="divthree" class="subdiv"></div>
</div>
```

this is your css code.in your css file

```
div.maindiv{
 width:99%;
 height:400px; /*use any height you want*/
 border:0px solid black;/*use 1px if you want and remove this after you positioned correctly*/
 position:absolute;
 top:300px;/*try with changing this according to your view*/
}

div.maindiv div.subdiv{
 width:33%;
 height: 100%;
 border:1px solid red;
 float: left;
 background-color: pink;
}
```

**this is easy if you use bootstrap.**

Comment: I don't use bootstrap, so maybe this is a bootstrap thing, but why are you using `position:absolute` and `top: 300px`. If you leave those out then the div will just stick itself up next to it's nearest neighbor and you don't have to play with sizes. Also this method doesn't work if you want the div to fit to the content rather than being fixed size.

Comment: I used it because I don't know the exact place he/she wants to put this. and if he/she want to change the position , the it will be easy